# Unity Character Movement

Tags: c#

Following a guide to make a top down rpg on youtube, So far our code is identical, however, when he compiles it, it allows for his character to face different directions, when I compile mine it tells me the name GetComponent does not exist and that the namespace float could not be found. What am I doing wrong? My code in bellow

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    
    private Vector3 moveDelta;

    private void Start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponenet<BoxCollider2D>();
    }
    
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        Float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
        //Reset MoveDelta
        moveDelta = new Vector3(x,y,0);

        //swap sprite direction, whether you're going right or left
        if (moveDelta.x > 0)
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        else if (moveDelta.x < 0)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,1,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You typed `GetComponenet` instead of `GetComponent` in your Start(), try:

```cs
Start() 
{
  boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
}
```

For the float issue, make sure to type it in lower case `float`, casing matters here.

*Note: `Float` (capitalised) doesn't exist in C# and `float` is a C# specific alias that is equivalent to the Type `Single`, so you can technically use `Single` and `float` interchangeably*